# Convert File Content in to Hex format

Tags: c, hex, decimal

Here I have one file `testdec.txt`.
In this File Contents are like below.

```
N = 162,27,79,83,101,69,213,78,188,215,254,75,222,74,204,124,53,108,240,157,213,109,189,143,226,71,120,134,57,27,64,230,126,218,4,249,150,44,182,223,70,241,96,113,61,115,54,13,209,53,236,157,164,126,202,150,121,13,180,223,50,84,239,39,188,44,119,71,50,220,196,107,218,66,106,24,203,13,150,135,231,65,240,236,32,226,166,2,243,26,236,253,185,88,196,58,255,146,93,202,57,219,57,160,62,160,225,167,0,209,231,110,156,106,8,119,47,255,46,87,76,10,243,99,48,147,47,197
E = 1,0,1
```

Here I want to convert `N and` E value in hex format and wants to write each decimal value in two bytes of hex value with out `comma` separator. I want to write this hex value in another `testhex.txt` file.

If decimal value will be only one byte of hex than I have to add `0` also in front of that hex value.
You can see in this thing in `E`'s value.`

And I want to do these all things in other file or same file. May be in another file is possible. we can not do in same file.

I want another `testhex.txt` file output file like

```
N = A21B4F536545D54EBCD7FE4BDE4ACC7C356CF09DD56DBD8FE2477886391B40E67EDA04F9962CB6DF46F160713D73360DD135EC9DA47ECA96790DB4DF3254EF27BC2C774732DCC46BDA426A18CB0D9687E741F0EC20E2A602F31AECFDB958C43AFF925DCA39DB39A03EA0E1A700D1E76E9C6A08772FFF2E574C0AF36330932FC5
E = 010001
```

So How can I Achieve this goal. Please Give me suggestion about this.

**EDIT : Try with this `testdec.txt` also As per BLUEPIXY code its gone in infinite loop.**

```
N = 137,72,247,73,196,168,11,223,107,232,230,189,125,211,175,123,12,235,2,231,123,244,84,184,214,143,144,189,38,103,237,173,129,68,158,92,8,141,76,60,76,98,54,39,7,48,148,45,76,105,52,191,255,245,117,156,25,122,244,65,79,110,244,17,23,110,128,239,117,70,46,140,178,75,230,126,242,100,77,194,42,187,241,110,218,215,242,118,186,92,133,26,175,167,158,16,113,123,105,114,161,23,79,197,76,102,103,93,230,174,120,128,194,34,104,42,253,131,122,49,30,212,205,237,119,71,108,95
E = 1,0,1 
N = 137,72,247,73,196,168,18,223,107,232,230,189,125,211,175,123,12,235,2,231,123,244,84,184,214,143,144,189,38,103,237,173,129,68,158,92,8,141,76,60,76,98,54,39,7,48,148,45,76,105,52,191,255,245,117,156,25,122,244,65,79,110,244,17,23,110,128,239,117,70,46,140,178,75,230,126,242,100,77,194,42,187,241,110,218,215,242,118,186,92,133,26,175,167,158,16,113,123,105,114,161,23,79,197,76,102,103,93,230,174,120,128,194,34,104,42,253,131,122,49,30,212,205,237,119,71,108,95
E = 1,0,1
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Here i am looking for way how can i do this? and i also did some coding regarding this. but i want to read only value after N and E. so how can i do this.Here i used strtok to seprate bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

- [man fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), this reads lines from a file.
- [man strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok), this extracts data separated by delimiters.
- [man atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi), this converts a string to an int.
- [man fprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf), this writes int values as hex strings to a file.

Comment: How can i get Value after E and N ?

Comment: Use whitespace as delimiter for getting the whole list of integers, then use comma for extracting each value.

Comment: strtok gives previous value (before value) of delimiter. suppose if i will apply strtok then i get only N = , i want after N = value

Comment: My apologies for the rudenes. My intent is that you learn how to fish instead of giving you fish.

Comment: Ok No problem Thats Good for me. Thanks Again For Your Help.

Comment: i will Try and if i will not succeed then back to you.

Answer (score 1):

One sample

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fin,*fout;
    char ch1,ch2;
    int data;

    fin=fopen("testdec.txt", "r");
    fout=fopen("testhex.txt", "w");
    while(1){
        if(EOF==fscanf(fin, "%c %c ", &ch1, &ch2))
            break;
        fprintf(fout, "%c %c ", ch1, ch2);
        while(EOF!=fscanf(fin, "%d%c%*[ \n]", &data, &ch1)){
            fprintf(fout, "%02X", data);
            if(ch1 == ',') continue;
            if(ch1 == '\n' || ch1 == ' '){
                fprintf(fout, "\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fout);fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf("%d%c", ...)` might return 0 if there's an alpha character or misplaced comma in the data; it would be best to use `while (fscanf("%d%c", &data, &ch1) == 2)` as the test in the inner loop.

Comment: Such user1089679 will check if necessary.

Comment: This program works for only two line if i will put more lines then its goes in infinite loop.

Comment: I am going to edit my testdec.txt then u can check this program with my testdec.txt

Comment: @user1089679 - This program assumes that the end of the data is a newline. E.g. N = 137,....,95\n E = 1,0,1\n . but your data is 95\n E = 1,0,1 space\n. Must slightly modify the program if it is correct format.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks for Your Reply can u please suggest me where i have to change in my code?

Comment: update for consider the case where there is a space at the end of the line.